# Why is numpy.int32 not recognized as an int type

Tags: python, numpy, types

I just spent half an hour looking into a bug in statsmodels' SARIMAX functionality that I could finally trace back to the fact that numpy.int32 fails type checks for int.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> foo = np.int32(3)
>>> isinstance(foo, int)
False
```

Is there a way to circumvent this kind of issue without explicit type conversions?
Should proper code even test for types and not check if a variable can safely be cast to a type?

Edit: My question is answered by an account of what technical limitations or design decisions are the cause of this behaviour and how to pythonically handle cases where both pure python's `int` and numpy `int32` or `int64` types might appear.

Comment: `<class 'numpy.int32'>` is not `<class 'int'>`. So if you are working with `numpy` instead of checking for `isinstance(foo, int)`, check for `isinstance(foo, np.int32)`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis What reason is there, not to inherit from pure python's int type, allowing `isinstance` to recognize the type?

Comment: I see more problems created than solved with that. This is all explained well in the proposed dupe. *My favorite answer is the second in vote-count*. I think we have to make an important distinction here between *integer numbers* as we, humans, know them and `integer types` as they are implemented in programming languages. You probably want to check for the 1<sup>st</sup> but actually check for the 2<sup>nd</sup>.

Comment: For reference: you can check against [numeric abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#module-numbers). `isinstance(foo, numbers.Integral)` seems to work for numpy types too.

Comment: `isinstance` works for classes in the `__mro__`.  Could you check the class of the `item`?

Comment: @hpaulj Which `item` are you referring to? I'm afraid I can't follow your comment.

Comment: `np.int32.__mro__` lists the inheritance stack of that class.  `isinstance` returns `True` for any class on that stack.  `np.int32` and `int` only share `object`.  `item` extracts a element from its `numpy` dtype, so `isinstance(np.int32(3).item(),int)` is True.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why *should* `numpy.int32` descend from `int`? `int` is a specific class. It is one way of representing integers. That doesn't mean that every class that represents integers should descend from `int`. `numpy.int32` has different semantics and different methods - for example, it has most of the functionality needed to operate like a 0-dimensional array - and inheriting from `int` isn't particularly useful for implementing `numpy.int32`.

On some builds of Python 2 (Windows only?), `numpy.int32` actually will descend from `int` (which is also 32-bit on those builds), but I believe this design decision dates back to a time when `int` performed wraparound arithmetic like `numpy.int32` instead of promoting to `long` on overflow, and when `operator.index` didn't exist. It was a more reasonable decision back then.

As for how to treat `numpy.int32` like `int`, `numbers.Integral` does a sort of okay job, but the implementation relies on people explicitly `register`-ing their classes with `numbers.Integral`, and people often don't think to do that. NumPy didn't add the `register` calls until [2014](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/2d73ff34f48980778b4e808afc76c0c1fa841ba7), 6 years after `numbers.Integral` was introduced. Similar libraries like SymPy still don't have the calls.

I find `operator.index` to be a better check:

```
try:
    real_int = operator.index(some_intlike_thing)
except TypeError:
    # Not intlike.
    do_something_about_that()
```

`operator.index` is the hook an int-like class has to implement to make its instances usable as a sequence index. It's a stricter check than `int(x)`, which would accept `3.5` and `'3'`. Since there's a concrete, easily noticeable impact if this hook is missing, it's more likely to be present than `numbers.Integral` support.

Comment: I had an environment with Linux + Python 2.7 (from source) + numpy 1.11.1 (from pip) where  `numpy.int64` descended from `int`, but `numpy.int32` did not.

Comment: **2014 was six years ago.** In 2020 and beyond, this answer is wrong to various degrees. [SymPy, for example, now registers its number types with the stdlib `numbers` API](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/5d1b2c6f04f583ec0beeea4b8238d4151b497332/sympy/core/numbers.py#L3937) just like NumPy. This means that `isinstance(some_intlike_thing, numbers.Integral)` now suffices to test integer-ness for everything except probably broken third-party hack jobs that you shouldn't care about anyway... *because they're broken.*

Comment: @CecilCurry: Note the absence of anything like `numbers.Integral.register(Integer)` in that file. `sympy.Integer` *still* isn't registered with `numbers.Integral`, and `issubclass(sympy.Integer, numbers.Integral)` is *still* False.

Comment: This is most likely a bug. The `numbers.Rational.register(Integer)` line should probably be `numbers.Integral.register(Integer)`. Yet, the `numbers` module is older than Python 3.0, almost 12 years old by now, and adoption is still so terrible that this lack of registration passes essentially unnoticed. A **lot** more people care about indexing than the number of people that care about the `numbers` module.

Answer (score 10):

`__mro__` lists the inheritance stack of a class:

```
np.int32.__mro__
Out[30]: 
(numpy.int32,
 numpy.signedinteger,
 numpy.integer,
 numpy.number,
 numpy.generic,
 object)

int.__mro__
Out[31]: (int, object)
```

For a basic array:

```
x=np.array([1,2,3])    
x.dtype
Out[33]: dtype('int32')
```

`isinstance` of classes on this stack returns True:

```
isinstance(x[0], np.int32)
Out[37]: True    
isinstance(x[0], np.number)
Out[38]: True
```

`int` isn't on this stack:

```
isinstance(x[0], int)
Out[39]: False    
isinstance(x[0], object)
Out[40]: True
```

`item` extracts a value from its `numpy` wrapper:

```
isinstance(x[0].item(), int)
Out[41]: True
```

@kazemakase suggests using the `numbers` module:

```
isinstance(x[0], numbers.Integral)
Out[47]: True
```

### edit

`isinstance` accepts a tuple of classes, so we can handle both the `int` and `numpy` cases with one test:

```
In [259]: isinstance(x[0], (int,np.integer))                                                           
Out[259]: True
In [260]: isinstance(x[0].item(), (int,np.integer))                                                    
Out[260]: True
```