# Why Numpy's int datatype is not of the same type as Numpy's int64 datatype?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Why does this give me false?

```
isinstance(np.int32(3.0),np.int)
```

Comment: As the docs say, int is platform dependent while int32 is guaranteed to be 32 bits long.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458438/why-is-numpy-int32-not-recognized-as-an-int-type#48467599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `np.int` is the same as python `int` data type.

Check [Difference between np.int, np.int_, int, and np.int_t in cython](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46416257/8353711) for more info.

```
>>> np.int
<class 'int'>
```

To check with `numpy.int32`, you can try with `np.int_`,

```
>>> isinstance(np.int32(3.0),np.int_)
True
```